# Sending out HTML emails via Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013

I have prepared an HTML for emailing out some information about a product I am working on. It has a few a images pointing to our webservers, even though I added our domain as trusted, when I try to view the email in Outlook 2013, it displays this message:

[image: Outlook image warning]

I get these emails all the time from other people and the message usually says, click to view images, and then the HTML displays properly.

Surely, there must be a setting I can set to change this prompt.

Comment: this belongs on [su].

Comment: Why don't you try embeding the images in your mailer, rather then calling through server ?

Comment: It depends on the Outlook client settings... The site is for developers. I'd suggest asking non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook does not check whether the domain is trusted. You can either make sure the images are embedded `(<img src="cid:xyz">` where xyz is the Content-ID MIME header of the image attachment) or you can set a special property on the client side (it can only be set on the client side in Outlook) that lets Outlook view the images.